# Why does the ThreadpoolExecutor code never stop running?

Tags: java

I run the code in IntelliJ IDEA and it would not stop. I use `exec.shutdownNow()` instead and it stops successfully. So, I think is the problem of `generator`, but I can't figure out what problem it is.

The main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrimeProducer generator = new PrimeProducer(new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10));
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    exec.execute(generator);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        generator.cancel();
    }

    //generator.get();
    exec.shutdown();
}
```

And the PrimeProducer class:

```
public class PrimeProducer extends Thread{
    private final BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue;

    PrimeProducer(BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue){
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                queue.put(p = p.nextProbablePrime());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public void cancel(){interrupt();}

    public void get(){
        for(BigInteger i : queue){
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The latest version that still can't work:

```
public class PrimeProducer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue;

    PrimeProducer(BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue){
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                queue.put(p = p.nextProbablePrime());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public void cancel(){Thread.currentThread().interrupt();}

    public synchronized void get(){
        for(BigInteger i : queue){
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `PrimeProducer` extend `Thread`, but you don't actually use it as a thread, you only use it as a `Runnable`, which is executed on a thread of the thread pool. The cancel has no effect, because it calls the `interrupt()` of a different thread than the one that is actually running. When you then call `exec.shutdown()`, the thread pool will interrupt its threads to signal them they should end, when then means `PrimeProducer.run` will stop.

Instead, use a volatile boolean to end your run (and implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`):

```
public class PrimeProducer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue;
    private volatile boolean cancelled;

    PrimeProducer(BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
            while (!cancelled) {
                queue.put(p = p.nextProbablePrime());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        cancelled = true;
    }

    public void get() {
        for (BigInteger i : queue) {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice answer! But I was still puzzled for what you said,"When you then call exec.shutdown(), the thread pool will interrupt its threads to signal them they should end, when then means PrimeProducer.run will stop."  I actually call exec.shutdown() in the end, but the main thread still does not end, the PrimeProducer.run has not stopped.

Comment: I also changed the PrimeProducer class( I have edited my question) to implements Runnable rather than Thread, and change the cancel method, but it still doesn't work.